# django cannot multiply non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in python & django coding.

I have this model :

```
class QuoteRow(models.Model):
    (...)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6, blank=True, null=True)
```

And these lines in another model 'Quote' :

```
 def _total_amount(self):
        return QuoteRow.objects.filter(quote=self.pk).aggregate(Sum('unit_price' * 'quantity'))
 total_amount = property(_total_amount)
```

In the shell :

```
q=Quote.objects.get(pk=2) // valid instance
q.total_amount
>>> TyperError: can't multiply sequenceby non-int of type 'str'
```

I can sum only the 'unit-price' column or only the 'quantity' one without problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this `Sum('unit_price'...` the built in `sum()` or is it coming from somewhere else?

Comment: The built in one from django.db.models import Sum. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this:

```
def _total_amount(self):
    req = QuoteRow.objects.filter(quote=self.pk)
    return sum([i.unit_price * i.quantity for i in req])
```

It takes one more line but it's clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
QuoteRow.objects.filter(quote=self.pk).extra(select = {'total': 'SUM(unit_price * quantity)'},)
```

Comment: Is there a way to enhance this because it returns a complex obect which is not very nice to work with ? Thx.